# Type mismatch in scala list. How to get List[String] from a sequence

Tags: list, scala, dataframe, type-conversion, sequence

I have a dataframe that's reading from a MySQL table. What I eventually what after some filters are applied is to create a `List[String]` element.
Here is what I did:

```
val ColSelection= df.select("session","name")
var sessionData=ColSelection.filter($"session".contains(element.toString()))
var nameSequence = sessionData.select("name").collect.flatMap(_.toSeq)
val sessionList =nameSequence.toList
```

But with this I am getting a `List[Any]` element causing mismatches when handling it later. 
How could I create straight a list that is defined to contain `String`s?
or how can I convert a `List[Any]` to list of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `List[Any]` to `List[String]` you could just `listAny.map(_.toString)`